# Make Android permission imply another permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am declaring new permissions in my app, one for read access one for write access. Is there a way that the write permissions can imply read permission? That way, if an app requests write-permission they are automatically given read permission.

Here is my manifest code as-is:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.CHANGE_MESSAGE"
    android:description="@string/permission_change_message"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.READ_MESSAGE"
    android:description="@string/permission_read_message"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

I want to give any app that has permission to `CHANGE_MESSAGE` also have permission to `READ_MESSAGE` without having to expressly declare `READ_MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used custom `Permission` Yet, but you can try this:

- `Permission Name One------->Point to one Activity--(m1(),m2(),m3())`
- `Permission Name Two------->Point to Second Activity--(m4(),m5(),m6())`

Suppose we want to give privilege of `Permission` Name Two to user when system grant `Permission` Name One. Then you can internally call m4(),m5(),m6() from `Activity` that point from `Permission` Name One.

Comment: Problem is, these permissions are controlling access to more than just activities/methods. The read permission is also restricting access to a broadcast.

Comment: you can define control access to broadcast inside methods using some conditions

Comment: I know that, but if I require `READ` permission through the broadcast, and the app only requests `WRITE`, it will be denied because `WRITE` doesn't imply `READ`.

Comment: I believe more thing can be done by showing some code,but access of resources can be control by if with some condition.share some code